# Is it possible for dwellers to have twins in fallout shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I could not find any information to support either way. **Can female dwellers give birth to twins?** If so, what are the odds of this happening?

Comment: Is there a reason you think this is possible?

Comment: The reason there is no information to saying neither _yay_ nor _nay_ is that there hasn't been any reason at all to suspect it would be possible. There is no need to disprove something that doesn't even appear to exist in the first place.

Comment: And oddly it shows to exist anyway. ^^

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible!! I have got some today! 
[image: twins]

Dalmatian gives 25% twins chance i think mine aas a rare

[image: pet stat]

This kitty was a legendary!

[image]

Comment: Harkness is an android and Star Paladin Cross is a cyborg. Just throwing that out there.

Comment: Nukapedia has a [list of pets](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_pets), but no listed bonus for dalmatian yet. Game Revolution has [all the pet cards](http://www.gamerevolution.com/faq/fallout-shelter/pets-full-list-of-dogs-and-cats-in-fallout-shelter-120985#/slide/20) that show up when you get the pet. The Dalmatian says "Rumors of huge litters are greatly exaggerated". Do you have a screenshot of the dalmatian's stat boost you could add? It's fine now, that would just be even better.

Comment: Anything to help! This dalmatian was a rare, so i imagine legendary is higher still

Answer (score 3):

There is no argument to support either way. That said, it is more likely **not** possible. If it was, it would at least be touched on, across the guides, the wikias etc.

That said, **it is possible to have twin dwellers**, as experienced by a user at [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/falloutshelters/comments/3aa386/is_it_possible_to_have_twins/). The user reports having received identical dweller cards from lunchboxes, and it was unrelated to breeding.

Comment: Moreover, since you can give the first name you cant to dwellers, while they take their mother's last name, you can actually have two dwellers with the same name, the same appearance, and the same stats. Not technically twins, though.

Comment: Indeed, I had forgot about renaming.

Answer (score 3):

I only wanted to add this screencap as a reply to a comment, but I don't have the reputation. So I'll abuse the system with an "answer" that isn't that much of an answer.

My Ms Bowman had two sets of twins prior to the triplets shown below, with Roxy equipped before and throughout the pregnancy with Three Dog as the father. FWIW, they are my two most charismatic dwellers, and spend most of their time together in the radio room.

This is in an obviously small vault, on iOS. I've had less luck with Roxy in a larger PC vault, perhaps one set of twins out of 10 pregnancies.

[image: Triplets with help from Roxy]

Answer (score 0):

I got Shakespeare out of a pet carrier and he gives +75% chance for twins. Judging by the fact that I have yet to see a pair of twins without him, I don't think it's possible unless you have a pet

Comment: Welcome the Arqade.  Your answer doesn't seem to add much to existing answers.